# A different version is showing in different command in a Debian container

Tags: debian, docker

I am running a docker Debian 9.6 container. But when I run "uname" it is showing Ubuntu. But, "cat /etc/debian_version" is showing Debian version 9.6.

```
root@a2bb8bf8e79c:/# uname -a
Linux a2bb8bf8e79c 4.15.0-39-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 24 17:09:54 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@a2bb8bf8e79c:/# cat /etc/debian_version
9.6
root@a2bb8bf8e79c:/#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker containers run on the host's kernel, `#42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 24 17:09:54 UTC 2018` is the [kernel section of the output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6943931/2402008). If you run `uname -a` on the host it should give you the same value for the kernel.